# Layered Navigation accordion not working

Tags: magento2, php

I have created a custom theme. Which is extended from blank theme.
 In the catalog page, there is no accordion. All filter fields expanded automatically.
I am using **Magento 2.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy **`Magento_LayeredNavigation`** folder from  `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma` to your theme path `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/` and do the static content deploy.

Comment: Thank u working perfectly